# How do I print the subtree where branch branched off master?

Tags: git

We have a project in git with lots of branches/tags.

We have a branch master and a branch b1 off master.

How do I get git to show me the commit where branch b1 branched off master. Can I get to print something like:

```
A
|
B <--E<--F<--b1
|
C
|
D <-- master
```

or just the tree below B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the tree below b1 you could do `git log b1 --not master`.

Useful when comparing branches is `git log --graph b1 master` to see your picture as a graph.